# .getJSON method is not working in Firefox and chrome. Works fine in IE

Tags: c#, jquery, json, visual-studio-2012

I have a .getJSON method. It is working fine in IE Browser and its is not working in other browser like firefox and Chrome. This is the code

```
<script src="Themes/Js/jquery_v_1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            url = "http://192.168.0.171:8080/api/account";
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
                debugger;
                $.getJSON(url, function callback(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#<%= ddlList.ClientID %>').append('<p>Name : ' + jqXHR.responseText + '</p>');
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

in Firefox and chrome,  control is not  coming inside the function callback.
Please have a look and advice me.

Comment: Why such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Is there an error reported in the console? If not, does the network traffic get sent? Does it return as/when expected?

Comment: which version of the jquery is suit for this. Please advice

Comment: use the latest jquery version

Comment: There is no restriction for jquery version usage. But It is best to go for the latest versions since there are a lot more features are available. Be cautious when you move to a latest version, some of the methods you used might have been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is properly working with IE but not with Chrome,You can try any of the Virtual Servers available like Python Server,

Follow the steps

1.Run the command in corresponding folder(In Linux)

**python -m SimpleHTTPServer**

2.Open Chrome Browser and browse for localhost:8000/filename

Answer (score 0):

I think the `debugger;` statement might only be supported in IE. Try taking it out

Comment: removed the debugger; . But no use. Still same issue

Comment: Just to be sure. You removed both of them, right? Do you get an error when debugging in chrome/FF?

Comment: Yes I Removed the debugger; But i am not getting any error message in chrome/FF. Control is not getting inside the the function callback(data, status, jqXHR)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now.

I have added the below code in Web api Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the support all..